# Define a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, a borel measurable funktion $f$ and a function $g$ that is not measurable such that $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Find a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $\Omega$, a measure $P$ on ($\Omega$,$F$), a real-valued borel measurable function $f$ and a real-valued function $g$ that is not borel measurable such that $f=g$ $P$-almost everywhere.

Can someone help me find an example?

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit example. You can prove the existence of  a Lebesgue measurable set $E$ of measure $0$ which is not Borel using a cardinality argument. You can then take $f=0$ and $g=I_E$.